# Prolog: Why doesn't this predicate fail with an empty list passed as an argument

Tags: prolog

I made a pretty basic predicate to explain my problem, so don't mind it's uselessness. I want the predicate to fail if an empty list is passed as the B argument,

```
predicate(_,[],_) :- fail.
predicate(A,B,C) :- 
write(A),
writeln(B),
C = true.
```

But when I enter this query:

`?- predicate(test,[],X).`

Instead of returning false(since it's supposed to fail), it execute the predicate and the output is:

```
test[]
X = true.
```

Why won't the predicate fail even if B is an empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the first clause fails for the query `?- predicate(test,[],X).`. However, when the first clause fails, the second clause is trigged and produces the observed output. To check that, you can use predicate  [`trace/0`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=trace/0):

```
?- trace, predicate(test,[],X).
   Call: (11) predicate(test, [], _26304) ? creep  % <= try first clause
   Call: (12) fail ? creep
   Fail: (12) fail ? creep
   Redo: (11) predicate(test, [], _26304) ? creep  % <= try second clause
   Call: (12) write(test) ? creep
test
   Exit: (12) write(test) ? creep
   Call: (12) writeln([]) ? creep
[]
   Exit: (12) writeln([]) ? creep
   Call: (12) _26304=true ? creep
   Exit: (12) true=true ? creep
   Exit: (11) predicate(test, [], true) ? creep
X = true.
```

If you want that `predicate/3` fails when called with `[]`as second argument, then you can define that predicate as follows:

```
predicate(A, B, C) :- 
    B \= [],  % this condition forces failure when B is the empty list
    write(A), 
    writeln(B), 
    C = true.
```

Examples:

```
[trace]  ?- predicate(test,[],X).
   Call: (10) predicate(test, [], _28066) ? creep
   Call: (11) []\=[] ? creep
   Fail: (11) []\=[] ? creep
   Fail: (10) predicate(test, [], _28066) ? creep
false.

[trace]  ?- nodebug.
true.

?- predicate(test,[],X).
false.

?- predicate(test,[a],X).
test[a]
X = true.
```